# Excluding the Bibliography from ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, tocbibind

I'd like to disable the inclusion of the Bibliography in my TOC via the notbib option of the tocbibind package. Still my TOC contains the entry Bibliography. My documentclass is scrreprt and my bibliography is generated via Citavi and BibTex.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, DIV=13, BCOR=10mm, , toc=chapterentrywithdots, cleardoublepage=plain, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1cm]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[graphicx]{} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%dt einstellung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%dt. Einstellungen
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[notbib]{tocbibind}

%...
\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
%...

    \bibliography{Literatur}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly. I think you have compiled your file just once before adding the question.

Comment: You do not need package `tocbibind` with a KOMA-Script class. Use class option `listof=totoc` and maybe `index=totoc`. If the ToC itself should also get an entry in ToC use `\setup{toc}{totoc}`.